# substitute symbole with a list of pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to substitute a pattern in the first line of files with another pattern for a list.

My first input file are like this:

```
^^
ATCGATCGACGATCGACGCTGATAGATCTAG
```

and I have a second file with the pattern:

```
MVs_Haguenau.FRA_01.20(D8)0012108720
MVs_Tours.FRA_01.200012110482
```

I would like as output something likte that:

```
>MVs_Haguenau.FRA_01.20(D8)0012108720
ATCGATCGACGATCGACGCTGATAGATCTAG
```

So to subtitute ^^ by > and the pattern.

I have tried something using sed:
`while read l; do for f in *.fasta; do sed -e  " s/\^^/${l}/" "$f" > "$f".txt; done; done < List_name.txt`
but without success.

thanks

Comment: Could you please do confirm if there are multiple entries present in your files? If yes then it will be good to have a samples with more lines your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: So I have several .fasta, each with this format
```
^^
ATCGATCG
```
and my pattern has a line for each of my input fasta files

Comment: So you do not want `MVs_Tours.FRA_01.200012110482` to appear anywhere in the output, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} 
       FNR==1  {close(f); 
                f=FILENAME".txt";
                c++; 
                if($0=="^^") $0=">"a[c]} 
               {print > f}' List_name.txt *.fasta
```

note that if the file doesn't match the pattern, corresponding replacement will be skipped in this logic.  Other alternative is skipping unmatched files, for that remove `c++` and change `a[c]` to `a[++c]`.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {rec[FNR] = ">" $0; next} FNR==1 {close(out); out = FILENAME ".tmp"} $0 == "^^" {$0 = rec[FNR]} {print > out}' patern.txt *.fasta

>MVs_Haguenau.FRA_01.20(D8)0012108720
ATCGATCGACGATCGACGCTGATAGATCTAG
```

Comment: thanks I will try it. 
But how to run it for several files?
I have for example 3 input .fasta 
file1.fasta
file2.fasta
file3.fasta
and in my pattern.txt file the 3 pattern to put.
So file for fasta 1 put pattern line 1, fasta 2 pattern line 2 etc...

Comment: hum maybe its not the good approach, because it substitute for all input .fasta the line 1 of pattern.

Comment: @Nico64: Yes it will replace `^^` in all the fasta files with matching line number pattern. If that is not what you want please provide an example in your question

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^/>/' file3|sed -e '/^^^/{R /dev/stdin' -e 'd}' file[12]
```

Insert a `>` at the beginning of each line of file3 and pipe the results to a sed invocation that replaces each line which begins `^^` in the file or files supplied as input.

N.B. In the solution above, two files are supplied as input i.e file1 and file2